# R Use of number 2 prefacing nrow function?

Tags: r, for-loop

Probably a silly question but what is the purpose of the number 2 in the below code, (specifically the 2:nrow)

```
 cumsum_Petal.Width <- iris$Petal.Width[1]   # Create new vector object

for(i in 2:nrow(iris)) {                    # Use nrow as condition
  cumsum_Petal.Width[i] <-                  # Calculate cumulative sum
    cumsum_Petal.Width[i - 1] + iris$Petal.Width[i]
}

cumsum_Petal.Width                          # Print vector to RStudio console
# 0.2   0.4   0.6   0.8   1.0   1.4   1.7   1.9   2.1   2.2
```

Comment: For `i-1` where `i=1` you would index the array at zero, which is common in other programming languages but not in R

Comment: In RStudio, type this to get help on colon operator (:) - `?":"`

Comment: This is to avoid an error with cumsum_Petal.Width[i - 1] :  cumsum_Petal.Width[1 - 1] doesn't exist

Comment: Some programming languages use 0-based arrays (where `vec[0]` is the first element); R (and some others) is 1-based, where `vec[1]` is the first element. In most if not all languages, if you try to access outside of the range of acceptable indices (e.g., "0" in a 1-based vector), then it is typically an error or invalid data. In R, indexing on 0 will return a 0-length vector, typically not what is expected or desired (or acceptable).

Comment: BTW, you can replace your `for` loop with simply `cumsum_Petal.Width <- cumsum(iris$Petal.Width)`, in case that wasn't obvious (or outside the purpose of this exercise).

Comment: Another btw ... are you aware that `x:y` is a sequence generator in R? It produces a sequence of integers starting at `x` through and including `y`, so `2:nrow(iris)` produces a vector of integers ranging from 2 to (in this case) 150.